# How To Load Local Copy of boostrap on nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My form uses bootstrap however; it cannot load bootstrap. At first I thought it might be because once it gets to the client, it then requests bootstrap.css. The following code does NOT work:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"> <!---->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="content">
        <meta name="author" content="My name">
        <title>title here</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS core -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" media="screen">
    </head>
```

...

JS:

```
/*
* Import modules
* Declare variables
*/
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

var port = 8080;

/*
* Read files on disc
*/

var homePage = fs.readFileSync("main.html");
var form = fs.readFileSync("form.html");

//Quick, hacky solution. Eventually, replace with if statements and dynamically load local copies or reference to an online source. Would that be elegant?
var bootstrap_css = fs.readFileSync("bootstrap.css");
var bootstrap_js = fs.readFileSync("bootstrap.js");
var jquery = fs.readFileSync("jquery-1.10.2.js");

/*
* Configurations
*/
app.use(express.bodyParser()); //Add body-parser middleware

app.configure('development', function(){
    console.log("executing");
    app.get("/bootstrap.css", function(req, res){
        res.end(bootstrap.css);
    });
});


/*
* Routing
*/

app.post("/contact-request", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end("Thank you " + req.body.name + "!");
});

app.get("/form", function(req, res){
    res.end(form);
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.end(homePage);
});

app.get("*", function(req, res){
    res.end("Error");
});


/*
* Begin Listening
*/
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Listening: " + port);
});
```

I would appreciate help! I am well aware that this is a terrible way of doing it. Please just humor me. I would also LOVE an explanation of what is happening internally.

[EDIT] I have everything in one directory. Boostrap is called bootstrap.css. I tried a variation of ./ and / references but to no avail. I figured this should work because in the form you simply use /doSomething.

Comment: Why not use static middleware instead?

Comment: I'm sure that would be a good question if I knew what it was. I'm a beginner. I'll figure that out later? But thanks for the suggestion. I will look it up!

Comment: Especially because you're a beginner, don't use what you're using now.  It's much simpler than that.  `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`  http://expressjs.com/api.html#express  Just make a public directory in your Node.js app, and anything you put in there is accessible automatically.

Comment: So static just offers everything in that folder 'statically?' Is the fact that root '/' offers up 'public/index.html' hard-coded into the middleware?

Comment: One reason your approach might not be working is because you are not sending the browser the proper MIME types for each file. You can see this sample for some of the common types that you need: https://gist.github.com/hectorcorrea/2573391

Comment: @user2316667 It uses `/` because no other path was specified with `app.use()`.  You can do something like `app.use('/something', middleware_here)` if you want.  As far as knowing what the index file is, yes, the index file is hard-coded into the middleware.

Comment: Due to the lack of documentation for express.static, I'm not gonna use it. I have so much more control via this method. So I want to solve my problem not using static.

Comment: Darn, I am a goof. I used "bootstrap.css" instead of "bootstrap_css." Works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [express.static()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#directory) middleware which configures to show static files from a certain directory.

```
/*
* Import modules
* Declare variables
*/
var express = require('express');
var resolve = require('path').resolve;
var app = express();
var port = 8080;

/*
* Configurations
*/
// @todo Read http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html
// use these instead
// app.use(express.json());
// app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.bodyParser());

/**
* Configure directories
*/
app.use(express.static(__dirname))

// /form returns form.html
app.use('/form', function(req, res, next){
    // dirname equals current path to this file + file you wish to send for requests
    res.sendfile(resolve(__dirname, 'form.html'));
});

// / returns main.html
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    // dirname equals current path to this file + file you wish to send for requests
    res.sendfile(resolve(__dirname, 'main.html'));
});

// etc

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Listening: " + port);
});
```

Comment: Firstly, Why as my solution not working and why does this work? What is it doing internally that my code was not? Correct me if I'm wrong: my app sent main.html. main.html requests bootstrap.css, my code should've sent that back. Third, thanks for the resolve and bodyParser hints. Finally, brb, gotta test something else before I...

Second, Where can I read about express.static? (i.e. the fact that it automatically serves index.html?

Comment: Arghh (pirate), as expected, this serves index.html and I want it to serve main.html. But if I reverse the order, it serves main.html. And if I understand correctly, this is unncessarily sending both main and index. I don't like this 'use' business. [edit] brb in 1 hr. [EDIT2] I really appreciate your answer but the spirit of my question was why.

Comment: express.static is deprecated (not even available anymore..) try to use "st"

Comment: @bodokaiser Got some documentation on that?  I've never read that anywhere, and it doesn't make any sense.  Some Googling didn't turn up anything either.

Comment: May I ask you to elaborate? What is 'st'?

Comment: Don't you mean staticCache is deprecated? It would show a warning like bodyParser if it was going to be removed... You can find more documentation on static with Connect which express is built upon (http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html). Using .get/post methods are useful for API calls but use implements a middleware which handles the request otherwise it'll move to the next which is the the catch all in your case (main.html). This could be a 404 error to act like a real server and you could check the req is for a route path and return main.html only if it was for the root path (/).

Comment: hmm no idea why I thought express.static is deprecated as they only discussed a remove: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1928 sry. "st" is isaacs static middleware package (does better cache)